# How can I set maximumSelectionLength while closeOnSelect is false in Select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2-4, jquery-select2

I have the following code:

```
$("#select2").select2({ closeOnSelect: false,
                        maximumSelectionLength: 5,
                        ...  // I have AJAX implemented here
                      });
```

When I have `closeOnSelect` to be `false` and have the `maximumSelectionLength` set, I'm able to select more than 5 items without any problem. When I click away from the dropdown while having more than 5 items selected and I try to add another, I get the message "You can only select 5 items".

Is there any workarounds to have these two properties work together without clashing?

I'm currently using Select2 4.0.1.

---

***Update:***

I took pratikwebdev's advise and added the following code:

```
$("#select2").select2({ closeOnSelect: false,
                        maximumSelectionLength: 5,
                        ...  // I have AJAX implemented here
}).on("change", function(e) {
    if(e.target.length == 5) {
        $("#select2").select2({closeOnSelect: true,
                               maximumSelectionLength: 5,
        });
    }
});
```

This actually will close the dropdown once I select 5 items and the `maximumSelectionLength` property will work properly. But now the `closeOnSelect` is true so each time I select something, the dropdown will close.

Is there a way to toggle `closeOnSelect`?

Comment: try if you can trigger `change ` event when user selects any value in dropwdown.

Comment: @pratikwebdev I'm trying to trigger a change event when value is selected but I'm not sure how to go about closing the dropdown when the length hits 5. Any ideas?

Comment: check out solution if it works for you.

Comment: [This is a known bug in Select2 4.0.1.](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3514)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work fine.

```
  $("#select2").change(function(){
      var ele = $(this);
      if(ele.val().length==5)
      {
        ele.select2('close');
      }
  });
```

Comment: I just gave this a shot and it seems to have a similar bug as my updated code: 1) Each time I select an item, the dropdown closes and 2) the list in the dropdown is now shortened to the previous 5 that I selected and rest of the options disappear.

Comment: Oh I didn't see your updated code. Let me give it a shot.

Comment: Yup that did it. Thanks so much!

Comment: @sparky Thats great. That was the problem with initializing select again. I will update answer with second solution only. I knew first solution is not feasible.

Comment: Is there a way to trigger "You can only select 5 items" label to appear, not only to close the dropdown?